# scala using calculations from pattern matching's guard (if) in body

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm using pattern matching in scala a lot. Many times I need to do some calculations in guard part and sometimes they are pretty expensive. Is there any way to bind calculated values to separate value?

```scala
//i wan't to use result of prettyExpensiveFunc in body safely
people.collect {
  case ...
  case Some(Right((x, y))) if prettyExpensiveFunc(x, y) > 0 => prettyExpensiveFunc(x)
}

//ideally something like that could be helpful, but it doesn't compile:
people.collect {
  case ...
  case Some(Right((x, y))) if {val z = prettyExpensiveFunc(x, y); y > 0} => z
}

//this solution works but it isn't safe for some `Seq` types and is risky when more cases are used.
var cache:Int = 0
people.collect {
  case ...
  case Some(Right((x, y))) if {cache = prettyExpensiveFunc(x, y); cache > 0} => cache
}
```

Is there any better solution?
ps: Example is simplified and I don't expect anwers that shows that I don't need pattern matching here.

Comment: `if` expects predicate, something that return `Boolean`. When `if` matches you know that it was `true`. If you have to reuse that predicate either you take arguments from different values, so you cannot cache it, or you are reusing value, which means you can group things in nested `match`es and maybe `if`s.

Comment: Yea... right. Point is that i rarely expect boolean value... question updated to use int instead. I don't need different values to calcuate `prettyExpensiveFunc`,

Comment: Nested `match` could work if I will also consume values that don't match predicate... in my case I will leave them. `collect` expects `PartialFunction` and I really need to have guard there

Comment: I really do understand what is wrong with this question to be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cats.Eval` to make expensive calculations lazy and memoizable, create `Eval`s using `.map` and extract `.value` (calculated at most once - if needed) in `.collect`

```
values.map { value =>
  val expensiveCheck1 = Eval.later { prettyExpensiveFunc(value) }
  val expensiveCheck2 = Eval.later { anotherExpensiveFunc(value) }
  (value, expensiveCheck1, expensiveCheck2)
}.collect {
  case (value, lazyResult1, _) if lazyResult1.value > 0 => ...
  case (value, _, lazyResult2) if lazyResult2.value > 0 => ...
  case (value, lazyResult1, lazyResult2) if lazyResult1.value > lazyResult2.value => ...
  ...
}
```

I don't see a way of doing what you want without creating some implementation of lazy evaluation, and if you have to use one, you might as well use existing one instead of rolling one yourself.

EDIT. Just in case you haven't noticed - you aren't losing the ability to pattern match by using tuple here:

```
values.map {
  // originial value -> lazily evaluated memoized expensive calculation
  case a @ Some(Right((x, y)) => a -> Some(Eval.later(prettyExpensiveFunc(x, y)))
  case a                      => a -> None
}.collect {
  // match type and calculation
  ...
  case (Some(Right((x, y))), Some(lazyResult)) if lazyResult.value > 0 => ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yea... but you lose patter matching on value... In your example you calculate using `value` and not extracted one. It is nice ... but does not simplify anything.

Comment: What you require exactly is simply speaking not possible. You cannot assign and pass values between matches. Each match is independent pure computation, not intended to share state between cases. You want to calculate shared state - you do it outside pattern matching, e.g. just before ot. Anything else is bending over backwards in order to achieve arbitrarily defined elegance that gives no actual benefits.

Comment: Oh... I don't need to pass between matches ... What I hoped to do is bind name to be used in `if` and in case body after `=>`. There is no simple way of doing that and your solution could be used in some cases like that. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not run the function first for every element and then work with a tuple?

```
Seq(1,2,3,4,5).map(e => (e, prettyExpensiveFunc(e))).collect {
  case ...
  case (x, y) if y => y
}
```

Comment: Because it is potentially one of many case clausures and it should be calculated only for some of them. It will also make it harder if it will be not `Int` but `Option[Either[Person, List[String]]]`

Comment: Then add another `match` layer to check if you need your calculated value or not.

Comment: I cannot due to `PartialFunction`. I don't want to match case where predicate is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I tried own matchers and effect is somehow OK, but not perfect. My matcher is untyped, and it is bit ugly to make it fully typed.

```scala
class Matcher[T,E](f:PartialFunction[T, E]) {
  def unapply(z: T): Option[E] = if (f.isDefinedAt(z)) Some(f(z)) else None
}

def newMatcherAny[E](f:PartialFunction[Any, E]) = new Matcher(f)
def newMatcher[T,E](f:PartialFunction[T, E]) = new Matcher(f)

def prettyExpensiveFunc(x:Int) = {println(s"-- prettyExpensiveFunc($x)"); x%2+x*x}

val x = Seq(
  Some(Right(22)),
  Some(Right(10)), 
  Some(Left("Oh now")), 
  None
)
val PersonAgeRank = newMatcherAny { case Some(Right(x:Int)) => (x, prettyExpensiveFunc(x)) }

x.collect { 
  case PersonAgeRank(age, rank) if rank > 100 => println("age:"+age + " rank:" + rank) 
}
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/hFbcAqH/3

Comment: Your solution doesn't work as far as I can tell - https://scalafiddle.io/sf/syYoZR6/0 `prettyExpensiveFunction` is evaluated as many times as many `case`s has to be checked for each value.

Comment: Yes ... You are right. It does what I've tried to do at beginning (it needs to be extracted once and it works similar to case with cache from question). Your sollution will cache value properly but code is more verbose. I guess there is no perfect solution :(.